# Feeding live data using SQL view in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, sql-view

For the reporting purposes:
I was under the impression SSAS Tabular Model does provide the live data feed in Power BI.

I am curios, does using the view provide the live data feed in platform like Power BI. I think it's not the view but depends on where the view is pulling the data from. 
Just confirming.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question lacks the details.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture works as follow:

1. Data are changed in the original data source
2. Data are loaded from the original data source into AAS
3. PBI is live connected to AAS reading the data stored in AAS

Therefore, as long as the data in AAS does not change, you will not observe any new data in PBI.